# Drag & Drop Attachment to List

Tags: list, attachments, drag-and-drop

I am using SPO. I would like to be able to drag and drop a document file (.pdf etc) to a new list item when using the New Item Form, rather than utilising the attach button from the ribbon and needing to browse for the file. Does ayone know if this is possible and the solutions available?

Comment: I don't think it is possible out of the box to drag and drop a attachment to the list.

Comment: Ok i thought that might be the case. Are you aware of any third party paid apps or custom code solutions?

Comment: I have the feeling provided links help to develop upload functionality. i would like to simulate the "join file" button Sharepoint functionality with a drag and drop zone. I tried using both dropzone.js and Sharepoint js functions (like OkAttach) but I failed. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You may try with some JavaScript libraries for this.

http://bitwiser.in/2015/08/08/creating-dropzone-for-drag-drop-file.html

https://css-tricks.com/drag-and-drop-file-uploading/

When you get file data, insert file to list item as attachment by REST API.

url: http://site url/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('list title')/items(item id)/AttachmentFiles/ add(FileName='file name')
method: POST
headers:
    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
    body: "Contents of file."
    X-RequestDigest: form digest value
    content-length:length of post body

Here are some threads for your reference.
http://www.sharepointyammertech.com/2015/04/How-to-upload-attachments-to-SharePoint-list-item-using-REST-services.html 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292553%28v=office.15%29.aspx#FileAttachments

Lee